# Error in Dowloading updates

Tags: updates, samba

[image: Error snapshot]

I keep receving this error message when i am trying to download the update , also i can't connect to wireless network anymore

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please click on `Details` on that message window, and edit your post to include what it shows? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you didn't add the key. If you're using the official Samba repo, they have the code to add the [key here.](https://www.samba.org/samba/download/)